# VSTS Error copying files to local drive

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, cd, file-copying

I have a requirement to publish a .net desktop application to an on-prem machine which I have now installed VSTS agent on successfully registered. The VSTS release can see the machine OK and it works until downloading the artifact.

I have below settings for Copy files in the Release Definition:-

[image: Copy Files Configuration]

the settings for Publish Artifact task is :-

[image: Publish Artifact Settings]

I want to copy the build output to a local folder on the designated machine. When release  process starts, the artifact is copied to the local machine under vsts work folder OK, however, when the Copy Files process start, it fails with error can't find the folder.

[image]

while this folder is available there on C: drive.

Any help is much appreciated.
thanks

[image]

Comment: Since you are using VSTS release, **both the variable `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` and the Publish Build Artifacts task can not be used**.

Answer (score 1):

`Publish Artifacts` is the wrong task to use for this. That's intended to be used in your build process.

Just use `Copy Files`.